# Android AVD emulator hangs while loading

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I seem to have messed up AVD Emulator and need some expert help in solving the problem.

Here are the symptoms:

1. When I try to open my_avd (my default avd) from AVD Manager, it takes a very long time to load (approx 10 - 20 mins). When loading completes, it just hangs and does not respond to any clicks (unlock mode!).
2. I try loading my app on this emulator, it is abandoned with:
   "emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.app.xyz.xyzactivity activity launch'!"
3. When trying to launch 'my_avd' from terminal ('...android-sdk-linux/tools $ ./emulator -avd my_avd'), the load time is less, but it abandons with a "Segmentation fault" error in terminal.

   - I have tried deleting & re-creating my_avd multiple times, but no go.
   - Have tried increasing the 'Device ram size' to 1024 also, but even that did not help.
   - Tried the 'Snapshot: Enabled' mode while creating my_avd, but that only worsens the problem.
   - Have reinstalled eclipse, android sdk, etc.

I am using Eclipse, Android 4.0 (API 14) on Ubuntu 11.x (x64 processor with ia32-libs installed).

Any help/ suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Ram

Comment: my suggestion delete the AVD and create a new one. this worked for me

Comment: That also did not help. Tried a few more things like disabling 'snapshot', but nothing seems to work. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try another API version. I have this problem with API 14 and 15, but works fine with all the others. If you can't get it to work with, for example, the API 8 or 10 then you got a problem with your AVD emulator. I would suggest you to let the Eclipse choose the device for you (based on the your target version and the devices registered on your AVD Manager). Check the configurations of the device and make sure that they are the same of the real device you're emulating. Here goes the Motorola_spice_key (android 2.3.3) config:

```
Name    : Motorola_spice_key   
Device  : 2.7'' QVGA(240x320:ldpi) 
CPU/ABI : ARM(armeabi)
Target  : Android 2.3.3 (Api level 10)
skin    : 240x320
snapshot: true
Memory - RAM/VMHeap : 512 / 16
Internal Storage: 200MiB
SD Card : 512Mib
```

Try this one. If fails, then you might have to reinstall the emulator.